# For $p,q,r\in P$, solve $3p^4-5q^4-r^4=26$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> For $p,q,r\in P$, solve $3p^4-5q^4-r^4=26$

I thought of breaking $26$ as $2\times 13$ and also factorising the equation if possible. But I can not proceed, please help.

Comment: $p$, $q$ and $r$ cannot be all odd.

Comment: What is $P$?  Primes?

Comment: yes, ofc. P=prime.

Comment: If you look at this mod $3$, you get $q^4=2+r^4$.  Since the only squares mod $3$ are $0$ and $1$, it must be that $r\equiv 1\pmod 3$ and $q\equiv 0\pmod 3$.

Comment: As one answer suggested, this equation has no integer solutions $p,q,r\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: See that at least one of $p,q,r$ must be even (check modulo $2$ ), then check modulo $4$ and see that exactly one of them can be even. Then do a little casework and check modulo $6$ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looked at mod $5$, we have

$$3p^4-r^4\equiv1\mod5$$

Since $a^4$ is either $0$ or $1$ mod $5$ for any $a$, we easily see that the displayed congruence has no solutions, prime or otherwise.

Comment: By [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Comment: @user236182, if you like.  But $5$ is small enough that one can also check it directly without breaking a sweat.

Comment: I like your solution. Short and simple!

Answer (score 3):

If $p,q,r$ are all odd then the LHS will be odd, which is never be $26$. Thus, amongst $p,q,r$, there must be at least one equal to $2$. Observe that $p > r$ and $p > q$. So $p$ can't be $2$.

If $r = 2$, then $3p^4 - 5q^4 = 42$, thus $q = 3$ and so there is no solution $p$.

If $q = 2$, then $3p^4 - r^4 = 106$. The LHS is either $0$ or $-1$ (modulo $3$), which means it can't be $106$.

Comment: Minor quibble:  There's no obvious reason you can't have $p=r$.  But it suffices to observe that $p$ must be greater than $q$ in order to conclude $p$ can't be $2$.

Comment: @BarryCipra You are correct. We can also exclude that case by seeing that, if $p=r$ then $q$ must be $2$, which leads to non-integer solution $p$.

Answer (score 1):

As CY Kwong remarked, $p$, $q$ and $r$ can't be all odd, in fact the number of odd ones must be even.  They can't all be $2$, so one of them must be $2$.

Considering the equation mod $3$, we find that we need $q \equiv 0 \mod 3$.
Thus $q = 3$.

Now we have two cases ($p=2, q=3$ or $r=2, q=3$), but neither works.  So there is no solution.